# How to make my docker container call my API that is im my docker host?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have an angular application in a container and want to make it call my API that is in my docker host. I want to do it so I could debug my API and make some tests.

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6.9.5-alpine
COPY . .
RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

How can I make it call my API that is in my docker host using a HTTP request?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to reach the host from the docker you can use `host.docker.internal` which would translate to the address of the host.

Comment: if i add the `host.docker.internal:ports` in the call it will work?

Comment: I can run `curl host.docker.internal:9000 -v` from inside my container to reach a port on the host. So I would assume this should work for you too.